# How do you detect the firware version

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have an Intel Card N 7260 on my Lenovo. I would like to know if the firwmare version supplied by Ubuntu 13.10, is older or matching the [upstream version](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) .

Could you tell me how to detect the firmware version ?

These are current upstream versions:

> 3.10+ iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0.tgz
>   3.13+ iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.24.8.0.tgz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect the firmware version being loaded with:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

You will see the firmware version being loaded, something like:

```
iwlwifi 0000:xx:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

If this is the case, you know that the former version you listed is being loaded. If you see 22.0.7.0, then you should update your firmware. Post back if you need guidance to do so.

I don't believe the -8 version will be called by the iwlwifi driver until the driver version in kernel 3.13; i.e. Ubuntu 14.04. You can tell what version your driver calls with:

```
modinfo iwlwifi
```

In my fully updated 13.10 system, it says:

```
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look in `/lib/firmware` folder if you have the latest:

```
ls -l /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-*.ucode
```

Comment: This is the output: `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode`, the readme from upstream says: `The "-8" in the filename reflects an interface/architecture version number.
It will change only when changes in new uCode releases make the new uCode
incompatible with earlier drivers.` So this helps very little to detect the version.